# Ubuntu Server Var directory deleted

Tags: filesystem

How can solve the problem of accidentally deleted var directory of Ubuntu amazon aws server.My website down right now.Support from amazon is paid service I am new to Ubuntu Hosting and unable to pay for support. Please help

Comment: Your instance is gone forever if you did not make a backup.

Answer (score 0):

There's usually some important stuff in `/var`, if you have a backup now would be a good time to restore. Or even reinstall Ubuntu and then restore your data from a backup.

It might be possible that your system will still boot & run after deleting `/var`, but since you're having problems now...

Comment: I am using Amazon aws server.How can I reinstall Ubuntu.I can only login to this server.

Comment: That sounds like something only Amazon can do... If you can still log into the server, then maybe you can get your programs (website?) going now or restore them from your own backup?